# Map and FindFirst

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it valid to use findFirst() and map() in pipeline.findFirst is shortcircuit method whereas map is intermediate operation.

```
this.list.stream().filter(t -> t.name.equals("pavan")).findFirst().map(toUpperCase()).orElse(null);
```

Is it valid to use map in pipeline like above??

Comment: What happened when you tried it? It might work better if you use `map(t -> t.name.toUpperCase())`.

Comment: You can also try `list.stream().map(t -> t.name).filter(n -> n.equals("pavan")).findFirst().map(String::toUpperCase).orElse(null)`. The first `map()` is an intermediate stream operation, but the second `map()` is not a stream operation. It's a method of `Optional`.

Comment: (Unrelated) You probably don't want to use orElse(null), just have the Optional as the result.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you **can** use `map` after `findFirst`. The Key thing to know here is that findFirst() returns an `Optional` and hence, you can't simply use the return value without first checking whether the optional has got a value or not. The snippet below assumes that you were working with a list of objects of Person class.

```
Optional<String> result = this.list.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.name.equals("pavan")) // Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.
    .findFirst() // Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty. If the stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.
    .map(p -> p.name.toUpperCase()); // If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

// This check is required!
if (result.isPresent()) {
    String name = result.get(); // If a value is present in this Optional, returns the value, otherwise throws NoSuchElementException.
    System.out.println(name);
} else {
    System.out.println("pavan not found!");
}
```

One more error with your snippet was where you were using `toUpperCase`. It needs a String, whereas the implicit argument that was getting passed in your snippet was an object of Person class.